# Programmatically Get the Incoming/Outgoing COM Bluetooth Port.How can do it in Windows Mobile 6 App in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I want to Print from windows mobile App through Bluetooth printer.What i am doing is that hard coding the COM port as below...

```
SerialPort comPort1 = new SerialPort("COM5", 57600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
comPort1.Open();

//Some thing to pint
//comPort1.WriteLine("PRINT");

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
comPort1.Close();
```

Its Not Proper Way,I want to search the application available bluetooth printer and connect with it.otherwise show a proper error message ["Bluetooth device not found/Selected Device is not a printer"]. please help me to found this, Anyone can direct me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write some code that can go through each port number on the device, testing all of the various settings to see if a port exists. Even then, I don't know of a good way to guarantee that the port is a Bluetooth printer.

Have you ever noticed that Microsoft displays a form for the User to specify the settings with?

[image]

Just saying, you might find it easier to present your people with a custom dialog box.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply.                                           The Bluetooth connection is actually mapped to two COM ports—one for incoming and one for outgoing traffic. On my test device the  port is COM5,and i want this port name programatically put in my  code,if user changed this com5 to com6 or else.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Bluetooth API might be more what you want.

See for instance my library 32feet.NET.  Lots of people use it for printing.  You can discover devices like this:

```
var cli = new BluetoothClient();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devList = cli.DiscoverDevices();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] selected = null;
foreach (var cur in devList) {
   ... chose one and set 'selected'
}
return selected;
```

[Discovery](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/Discovery)

You can connect to a printer like:

```
BluetoothAddress addr = ... e.g. selected.DeviceAddress;
var cli = new BluetoothClient();
cli.Connect(addr, BluetoothService.SerialPort);
using(var peer = cli.GetStream())
using(var wtr = new StreamWriter(peer)) {
   wtr.WriteLine("Hello world");
}
```

[General Bluetooth Data Connections](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/General-Bluetooth-Data-Connections)

Comment: Thank u so much for Ur reply.i heard about 32feet.but i don't know whether it help me in my case.i want to get the com port which is active now for Bluetooth action..how it get and use using 32feet library.?

Comment: Why do you want the COM port?  In your example above you write to it from the same program...  If that's the case then 32feet.NET wioth BluetoothClient will be perfect for you.  [continued]

Comment: ...  If you instead have a different app that writes to the COM port then you will need the COM port lookup method, or a COM port set-up method...  BTW which Bluetooth stack on is on the PDA?  MSFT, Widcomm, StoneStreetOne Bluetopia...?