# Get Bluetooth COM port direction in C#.Net

Tags: c#

I have the COM port for the Bluetooth serial communication in the windows 7 machine. How do I get the direction of the COM Ports in C#, i.e whether is it an incoming port or outgoing port.

Thank you for your extended support. Attached is the screen shot[image]

Regards

Comment: Wasn't [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7911874/1997232) earlier. Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad5fe4a6-9be8-4780-a8e7-7742533a2b4d/determining-bluetooth-com-port-assignments-in-windows-7?forum=wdk).

Comment: Serial ports hardware is always bi-directional.   Unless a custom driver is used that only allows one direction all ports are bi-directional.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg problem, how do you know the COM port number in the first place?  These problems won't go away until talking to Bluetooth devices gets easier in C# without having to rely on the serial port emulation hack.  The Windows.Devices.Bluetooth namespace is a very good way to get there but that's never going to come to Win7.  It will take a while, it is new XP.

Comment: Check the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327458/get-bluetooth-com-ports?rq=1) question. It worked for me.