# How to get OutGoing ComPort of bluetooth device in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, serial-port

I am working on a C# application. When i pair a bluetooth device with my PC, i get two Com Ports, i.e.

[image]

One of these ports is used for incoming connections and one for outgoing. I have to find the port which is used for outgoing connection. This information is present in the bluetooth seetings i.e.

[image]

My issue is that i have to find this outgoing port programmatically in C#. How can i get this info in C#.

Comment: It is a littl ebit long code to past it here. but [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) provides methods to enumerate such comports (and provides association with Bluetooth device by its MAC). It also allows to create such vCOM from your application.

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to use WMI to query [Win32_SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-serialport)

Comment: Page not found @MikePetrichenko

Comment: it does not give any information regarding the direction @stuartd

Comment: Just checked - works. try from main page: https://www.btframework.com. Look at BluetoothManager demo->Enum vCOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do this with the help of accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327458/get-bluetooth-com-ports?rq=1) question.